# How to compare value lengths/sizes in 2 dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, iteration, max

I'm super new to Python. I have two dictionaries I need to compare values to. One has key with tuples as value(s?) associated with it, the other has keys with integers as its values.

Example:

```
type_fruits = {'Apple': ['red', 'green'], 'Orange': ['naval'], 'Pear': 
    ['Asian'], 'Banana': []}

fruits_max_amount = {'Apple': 3, 'Orange': 2, 'Pear': 1, 'Banana': 3}
```

Say I want to add another type of pear, but my value for 'Pear', in the fruits dictionary is 1, so it's full. How do I show that it's full and can't be added?

I have:

```
fruit = input("Enter the type of fruit to add: ")

if fruit in type_fruits:

    if len(type_fruits[fruit]) == fruits_max_amount:

        print("Already full.")
```

Which is not working.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is what you want:
    if type_fruits[fruit] == fruits_max_amount[fruit]:

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare the value corresponding to the entry in the fruits_max_amount dictionary.  Currently you are comparing the length to the whole dictionary.

```
fruit = input("Enter the type of fruit to add: ")

if fruit in type_fruits:

    if len(type_fruits[fruit]) == fruits_max_amount[fruit]: # max for fruit

        print("Already full.")
```

Comment: Thank you - like I said I'm new to this and it's still confusing so I really appreciate you helping me out today!